# Spring Security 3.1.1 + Jboss 7 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I'm having some throblems when I try to deploy an application which use spring securety on Jboss, the error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
```

This is my applicationContext-securety.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->      
    <!--<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>-->
   <http pattern="/ext/**" security="none" /> 
       <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" /> 
      <http pattern="/**" security="none" /> 

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="tendwebEntryPoint">            
    <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->        
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
    <!-- Filter -->          
     <custom-filter ref="mockimiAuthenticationFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>       
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />    

 <beans:bean id="imiAuthenticationFilter" class="com.tend.imi.web.security.imiAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="tendwebFilter" ref="tendWebFilter" /> 
    <beans:property name="imiUserDetailsService" ref="imiUserDetailsService"/>          
</beans:bean>   

<!-- Filtro de la tendweb -->
<beans:bean id="tendWebFilter" class="Gci.utils.http.LoginFilter" /> 

<beans:bean id="tendwebEntryPoint" class="com.tend.imi.web.security.imiwebEntryPoint" />

<beans:bean id="imiUserDetailsService" class="com.tend.imi.web.security.imiUserDetailsService" />
```

And I'm using this in the web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

      <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Can anybody help me? I searched a lot but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sir Celius for your answer.

Finally I resolved my problem. The error was in the declaration of contextConfigLocation in the web.xml, I had this:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I don't know why, but the use of the special character "*" doesn't like to Jboss, I just change this and everything works.

I deployed this application in tomcat and weblogic and this never happend ... I think its an error that Jboss has to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a double for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812902/a-universal-match-pattern-is-defined-before-other-patterns).

The problem is that you say `/**` is open to any user, but then you try to use `auto-config`.

According to the error code, this causes conflict because spring doesn't know whether `/index.jsp` is supposed to be open for all users or only authenticated ones.